# Size attribute doesn't have any options

Tags: magento2.3, product-page, size

Size attribute dropdown in product detail page doesn't loading options. If I reload the page then the options are apprearing. But I want it to load on first instance. I have tried reindexing and cache cleaning. The products are configurable products. Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: do you have third party extension working on product page?

Comment: @Asad Ullah Yes I have a reviews extension in product page.

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0):

I encounter this issue before while using custom extension.

It is caused by the layout on product page there are multiple layout calls some by ajax some by other means before reload it will not show options because it is not refreshing that specific layout from where options are  coming but on reload it will refresh all layouts on that page along with that layout thats why it is behaving like this.

hope this helps

Comment: How did you solve this issue?

Comment: try to find the LAYOUT that is running that specific PHTML file and override that LAYOUT in your custom extension